# indentation syntax error

Tags: python

How do I resolve the `Unindent does not match any other indentation level` syntax error in line 3 of this code?

```
if userInput==1:
   oneD()
elif userInput==2:
    twoD()
elif userInput==3:
    threeD()
elif userInput==4:
    fourD()
elif userInput==5:
    fiveD()
```

Comment: Have you mixed tab and spaces in your code?

Comment: Try using [an IDE](http://sopython.com/wiki/Python_IDEs). Personally I prefer PyCharm. All you'd have to do when indenting is press "tab", and it will move the cursor 4 spaces to the right.

Answer (score 0):

It should look like this;all evenly spaced:

```
if userInput==1:
    oneD() #this one was not spaced evenly like the rest of your code
elif userInput==2:
    twoD()    
elif userInput==3:
    threeD()
elif userInput==4:
    fourD()
elif userInput==5:
    fiveD()
```

Answer (score -1):

i think spaces are mixed in your code, try fixing it.

```
if userInput==1:
    oneD()
elif userInput==2:
    twoD()
elif userInput==3:
    threeD()
elif userInput==4:
    fourD()
elif userInput==5:
    fiveD()
```

Answer (score -1):

Your spaces are mixed in your code, you've been using a mixture of tabs and spaces. Try fixing this by making them all using TAB or using normal spaces.